# Getting a drawable in monodroid?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm using this code to get a drawable and use in a `SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` call:

```
Drawable d = Resources.System.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.navigable_icon);
textView.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null,d,null);
```

The problem is that when calling the `GetDrawable` method I allways get an exception stating:

> Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Resource ID
>   0x7f020009

The `drawable` exist as any other I use in xml in the `drawable` directory. Could anybody guess what's hapenning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you calling this from?

As far as I can see the Resources class does not have a System property, and intellisense tells me that this is the way to get a Drawable:

```
var drawable = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.navigable_icon);
textView.SetCompoundDrawablesWithInstrinsicBounds(null,null,drawable,null);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have seen in all posts here at stackoverflow. But for me Resources.GetDrawable() does not exist. Would you mind telling me what have you imported?

Comment: These are my imports: using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS; Resources is a prop you can access through an activities context.

Comment: In my case I can see this method in resources -> public static Resources System { get; }. I have last monodroid version :/.

Comment: Summary of System:
Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources), and is not configured for the current screen (can not use dimension units, does not change based on orientation, etc).

Comment: So back to my question, are you calling Resources.GetDrawable from an Activity?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was that I was tring to access it from a data adapter.

Comment: A solution could be to pass a context reference to that data adapter and then do Context.Resources.GetDrawable()